# Swap between MVC routing and Durandal routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, single-page-application, durandal

Long story short: We're trying to set up Durandal SPA in our pre-existing ASP.NET MVC website. What's we're going for is the ability to hide the SPA behind a feature flag, to where we can enable the SPA flag and have our website adjust accordingly.

We have that portion of it working. However, what we had to do is prefix all of our routes with "/app#" and then tack on the controller/action. For example, "Index" would become "app#Index" in the URL. Durandal routing works just fine with this approach - it pulls the necessary views into place.

What we would like is to use the same routes instead of prefixing each one with "app#" - essentially use Durandal routing when the SPA flag is enabled, otherwise use normal MVC routing, but keep the routes the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using mvc? and what version ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know about modules requires convention of the Durandal, will be very simple to understand, you just need to insert this configuration in the Web.config:

*Web.config*

```
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*"  type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
     <add name="HtmlFileToMvcHandler" path="App/views/*/*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
```

Observe that i created the handler **"HtmlFileToMvcHandler"** with this pattern **"App/views/*/*.html"**  i used that pattern because my CRUD convention, and with this i told to the MVC handler that all of the requests that comes with this pattern will be handled. But now you need  handle the requests that will came. So you can use  the `RouteAttribute` like this:

```
    [Route("App/View/Home/index.html")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

or map that route in the route config like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Name",
            "App/views/{controller}/{action}.html");
```

My english will be better in the next time XD